# SimpleForm: has_many/belongs_to with <select> does not pre-select the current value in the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, html-select, simple-form

I have the following models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :freelanced_projects, foreign_key: :freelancer_id, class_name: 'Project'

  scope :freelancers, -> { where(role: 'freelancer') }
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :freelancer, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :freelancer_id
end
```

I use SimpleForm to generate a nice form in the view:

```
= simple_form_for project do |f|
  = f.input :freelancer, as: :select, collection: User.freelancers, include_blank: true
```

The problem is, that in the displayed form, the freelancer is not pre-selected.

[image: Screenshot]

If I change `f.input :freelancer` to `f.input :freelancer_id`, then it seems to work:

[image: Screenshot]

But, as you can see on the screenshot, then the translations are missing, and I'm pretty confident that I shouldn't add an `_id` to the keys in the translation files.

So what's the problem here? How can I solve it?

Comment: I don't use simple_form so I am not familiar with the syntax. Is it not possible to use the Rails way `f.select :freelancer, options_for_select ()` ? Your options for select has two elements: the first one is an array constituted of subarrays like [['£', 'pound'],['€','euro']] where the first string is your printed text and the second string the passed value. And the second, comma separated element, is your current value like : @record.currency. (@record is the model record passed to the form, project in your case)

Comment: Actually for a collection the method is : options_from_collection_for_select. It is well documented to preselect a value.

Comment: I tried it using `f.select :freelancer, options_from_collection_for_select(User.freelancers, 'id', 'name'), include_blank: true`, but it also does not work. I have the feeling that maybe something's wrong with my association definition...?

Comment: because you didn't include a fourth param for the default value here `options_from_collection_for_select(User.freelancers, 'id', 'name')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simply to user `f.association`:

```
f.association :freelancer, collection: User.freelancers.collect { |user| [user.name, user.id] }, include_blank: true
```

Important: user `:freelancer`, not `:freelancer_id`! Simple Form will take care of naming the name and ID of the `<select>` correctly, while also looking for the correct translation value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
= f.input :freelancer, as: :select, collection: User.freelancers.collect { |freelancer| [freelancer.name, freelancer.id] }, include_blank: true
```

Replace `freelancer.name` with whatever the name of the field for freelancer name is called.

Comment: Thank you. But doesn't have an effect.